# "Would I be ready" or "am I ready"

Tags: conditional-constructions, will-would

Consider this sentence:

> I study medicine too, but am I ready to act like them in a similar situation?

Suppose you finished reading a book about the actions of some people in battle filed. Now you want to put yourself in their shoes. Should I use "am" or "would be" in the sentence above?

Comment: Both would work.

Answer (score 1):

The difference would be dependent on what you are trying to say.

Consider the 2 possibilities:

1. > I study medicine too, but **am I** ready to act like them in a similar situation?
2. > I study medicine too, but **would I be** ready to act like them in a similar situation?

#1 is questioning **are you** ready **in this present moment in time** if in a similar situation? Whereas

#2 is questioning **would you be** ready **in the future** in a similar situation?.